# com.google.android.maps does not exist strange error

Tags: android, google-maps

I can't build my android project, it says that com.google.android.maps does not exist. It is way strange because in my project in libraries I have them. I rebuild the build.xml. The import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity; is not marked as error. What should I do?

```
Handling Resources...
Generating resource IDs...
C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml:600: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
Compiling 13 source files to C:\Users\iie\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication3\bin\classes
C:\Users\bla\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication3\src\menu\dot\MapMapa.java:10: error: package com.google.android.maps does not exist
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
C:\Users\bla\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication3\src\menu\dot\MapMapa.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
public class MapMapa extends MapActivity {
  symbol: class MapActivity
C:\Users\bla\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication3\src\menu\dot\MapMapa.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
        super.onCreate(icicle);
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class MapMapa
C:\Users\bla\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication3\src\menu\dot\MapMapa.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
         setContentView(R.layout.map);      
  symbol:   method setContentView(int)
  location: class MapMapa
C:\Users\bla\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication3\src\menu\dot\MapMapa.java:19: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
C:\Users\bla\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication3\src\menu\dot\MapMapa.java:26: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
6 errors
C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml:580: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml:600: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: can you please post the console error?

Comment: See this if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284022/package-com-google-android-maps-does-not-exist-intellij

Comment: I've seen it, I'm using netbeans, but I have changed everything to google api, still nothing :/

Comment: http://www.anddev.org/map-problems-f26/mapactivity-problem-package-maps-does-not-exists-t12811.html

Comment: I've also tried it. The problem is I have the maps in libraries [ and I don' have an context menu in Libraries [ but only with this project ] ].

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you

- install the Google APIs in your Android SDK (this means the "Google APIs" choice instead of the "Android X.x" one)
- specify to use this library in your manifest XML:

  ```
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
  ```
- choose "Google API" as your "Build Target", *not* the "Android X.x" one.

FYI, when testing with the emulator AVD, you need to launch the "Google APIs" version instead of the "Android X.x" one.

Comment: u see it is strange, because I have the library maps.jar in my libraries, but the error is still the same. I've done all these things u mentioned

Comment: Try doing a completely clean build.  In Eclipse you shouldn't need to manually put the maps.jar into your project - it should be picked up automatically from using the "Google APIs" instead of "Android X.x".

Comment: I can't make any build, I've tried clean & build but always stack with this error

Comment: if you are using Gradle, change compileSdkVersion=x to compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:x" where is your SDK version

Answer (score 2):

ok, finally I managed to sort it out:

here is a link with everything:

http://code.davidjanes.com/blog/2009/11/13/18-hours-of-jar-hell-with-android-google-maps/

sorry for answering my own question