# package com.google.android.maps does not exist "osmdroid" Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, osmdroid

Hi I know this question asked a lot but none of them help me to fix my problem.
I simply want to import [this](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) Project to my android Studio but I give this error message

```
Error:(15, 39) error: package com.google.android.maps does not exist
```

and this is my SDK:

[image]

I try clean , rebuild , invalidate cache but none of them help me.

Comment: add google  play services  as  dependency in build.gradle file

Comment: they add that https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-third-party/build.gradle

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284022/package-com-google-android-maps-does-not-exist-intellij

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748273/android-gradle-how-to-build-for-android-google-apis-4-2-2-not-for-android-4-2-2

Answer (score 1):

osmdroid contributor here.

osmdroid-android, which is the primary map engine does not require google play services.
osmdroid-thirdparty does need since it provides a wrapper for using gmaps with osmdroid apis

if you're building for source:  osmdroid can be built with maven (which currently has issue with play services) and gradle. suggest you use gradle with android studio

otherwise use this

`dependencies {
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-thirdparty:5.0.1@aar'
 }`

Answer (score 0):

I dont think osmdroid does need googlemaps library. But anyway, have you tried adding google-play-services library to build.gradle?

If you havent you can do this by following steps

- Click on Project Structure
- Go to Dependencies Tab
- Click + button
- Select com.google.android.gms:play-services and click ok
- Rebuild the project

Comment: Hi thanks for your attention but I want import sample library from osmdroid page in github and in theire sample project yes they add google-play-services https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-third-party/build.gradle